# Como faço para pegar a localização no google maps api de acordo com o clique do usuário?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps, localização

Eu entrei no site do google maps api e vi como colocar e utilizar a api no meu site, porém só consegui fazer com que cadastre um local de acordo com o que o usuário digita. Para uma melhor experiência, eu queria que quando o usuário clicasse em algum ponto do mapa, aquela latitude e longitude fossem salvas no banco de dados. Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Obs: Não é a localização que o usuário está, mas sim a que ele clicar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

    function initialize() {
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.949132746636568, -44.194307630538844);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: latlng,
          draggable: true,
          anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
       });
        var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                window.alert("O local retornado pelo preenchimento automático não contém geometria!");
                return;
            }

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }

            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);          

            bindDataToForm(place.formatted_address,place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());
            infowindow.setContent(place.formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0]) {        
                  bindDataToForm(results[0].formatted_address,marker.getPosition().lat(),marker.getPosition().lng());
                  infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
            }
            });
        });
    }
    function bindDataToForm(address,lat,lng){
       document.getElementById('location').value = address;
       document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
       document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: Pode explicar o que está sendo feito no código, ou inserir comentários nas linhas mais relevantes?